# Maximise a windows application using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to maximize a desktop application with robot framework. I read somewhere that i could use key combinations Windows + Up Arrow but how do i implement it ? Can someone share the code for it please ?

Comment: RF does not ship with ui automation libraries by default.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the PyAutoGui library for this.

```
import pyautogui
def maximize_window():
    pyautogui.hotkey('win','up')
```

and import this function as a library to your Robot Framework file.

Maybe pressing F11 (pyautogui.press('f11')) might also work, instead of Windows key + Up.